# how to convert a json array into java object?

Tags: asp.net, gson, android-volley

i create an error handling system with microsoft asp.net identity it return back error by using an enum as json model

```
public enum ErrorType
{
    InvalidPassword,
    TooShortPassword,
    NullUserName,
    InvalidUserName,
    NullEmail,
    InvalidEmail,
    DuplicateUserName,
    DuplicateEmail,
    OtherIdentityErrors,
    LoginIncorrectUserNameOrPass
}
```

and i have a class that create a list of error from that

```
public class ErrorModelJson
{
    public ErrorModelJson()
    {
        ErrorTypes = new List<ErrorType>();
    }
    public List<ErrorType> ErrorTypes { get; set; }
}
```

when a user send a request login if user name or password is incorrect  login action method return a json have a list of error

```
private ApplicationUserManager UserManager => Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(UserLoginJson userLoginJson)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userLoginJson.UserNameOrEmail) ??
                   await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLoginJson.UserNameOrEmail);
        if (user == null || !await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, userLoginJson.Password))
        {
            var errorJson = new ErrorModelJson();
            errorJson.ErrorTypes.Add(ErrorType.LoginIncorrectUserNameOrPass);
            errorJson.ErrorTypes.Add(ErrorType.InvalidPassword);
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorJson));


        }
        IUserManagement userManagement = new UserManagement();

        return Ok(userManagement.GetUserLoginReturnJson(user));
    }

so in my android application i have an enum ErrorType and a class ErrorModelJson to parse received json to ErrorModelJson to create a list of error my android app recieve a json as below
{"ErrorTypes":[9]}
```

and i'll convert this json to ErrorModelJson by gson and volley with these code but i get my model null can you help me?

```
 @Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
    NetworkResponse response = volleyError.networkResponse;
    switch (response.statusCode)
    {
        case 400:
            String data=new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data);
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            ErrorModelJson errorModelJson1 =    gson.fromJson(data,ErrorModelJson.class);
            errorModelListener.onError(errorModelJson1);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not dig deeply in the code, but i would suggest to convert the json array to string then re parse it to array object.